# 301 Redirects and Launching a New Version of a Website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I'm about to launch a new version of a client's website. They get a lot of traffic, and have significantly high rankings on google with their keywords / phrases. To get to the point, I don't want them to lose their ranking.

**My question:** What is the difference of adding 301's from old pages to the new vs just re-indexing on Google's webmaster tools? Will I lose the rankings even with 301 redirects?

The domain remains the same though the NS is changing but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: SEO questions are off-topic here. You might ask on [webmasters.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Comment: Are you sure about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo

Comment: Quite sure. You'll find that the first few questions in that tag have all attracted close votes. I didn't check further.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would chose 301 personally, as the load on your server is minimal and the authority of the previous page would transfer to the new page.

If you don't do a redirect, links to the old pages will return a 404, which means the inbound links will be gone and you'll start from scratch.

Comment: You're right. I'm just not sure if releasing a new version of a website is sort of a catch 22 with page rankings. Thanks.

Comment: Creating a new version w/ added 301s wouldn't be an issue.